# WPF - Access children from trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, styles, itemcontainerstyle

I have a `ListBox` declared like I show down there. The point is that in the Item definition I have plenty of stuff with grids and elements. I want to change the visibility of one Image in the item only to make it visible only when the element itself is selected.

I managed to change, for instance, the background and the general looking of the Item when it is selected but I cannot access the inner elements :(

```
<ListBox stuff stuff stuff>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="local:Patient">
            <grids , borders, things, stuff
                <Image Name="image1" source opacity stuff/>
            </ grids bordes and design in general>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <!--HERE I WANT TO CHANGE VISIBILITY OF THE IMAGE-->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.Template>
        <!-- some other styles when deselected and other things -->
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

I tried using:

```
<Setter TargetName="physiciansSettinsImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
```

But It cannot be set on a Style Setter. Any clue?

The whole design is fairly complex so I would like to avoid as much as possible recoding it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the trigger to `DataTemplate`.

I suppose ***image1*** `Visibility` is `Collapsed`

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource=
        {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=
            {x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="image1" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Now when the item is selected your `Image's Visibility` is set to `Visible`.

Comment: So sweet bro. Fast and clean. I've to admit that the whole thing is a bit confusing for me but.. bit by bit :)